# Max Bottom a Popup Div

Tags: css, html

I have a popup `div` which appears in the *center* of my screen:

```
 ---------------------------
 |           15%           |
 |     ---------------     |
 | 15% |             | 15% |
 |     |             |     |
 |     ---------------     |
 |          15%            |
 ---------------------------
```

I like the left side, top side and right side. But the bottom I don't like.

What I would like it to do is:

1. Adjust its size to the `height` of the content ( I think that's `height: auto`)
2. Not go bigger than the `15%` gap at the bottom.
3. Bare in mind inside this `div`, is a child `div` which has `overflow-y: auto`, inside this are `div`(s) which `float`.

This was my code:

```
    #toPopup1, #toPopup2, #toPopup3 {
        font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        color: #333333;
        display: none;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-right: 15%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 15%;
        bottom: 15%;
        width: 70%;
        z-index: 222;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Then I removed the `bottom:15%;` with `max-height:70%;` however the result I got was a much smaller box (almost one line in `height`), please advise?

Comment: It would be great to have the HTML code to and a fiddle reproducing you problem would be even better. (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: the smaller box with the max-height is because with setting top and bottom, you actually forced the box to go from 15% top to 15% bottom. Now with the max-height, it will just not get bigger than 70%, but you would need the content to push it up. You might add a min-height as well so that it is at least a certain height even with no or little content.

Comment: I will see what I can do with JSFiddle.

Comment: Sorry JsFiddle does not work with my code.  Or more like my code does not work with JSFiddle.  If you go to my webpage www.allcoles.com/index.php and click the link forgotten password.  You will see the silly small box with max-height: 70%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I am guessing :

When you replace `bottom:15%` by `max-height:70%` the height of the div is calculated by it's content.

You say the divs inside are floated so they don't extend the height of their parent therefore the popup div has a height of 0 (+ borders, padding and margins if there are any).

Several solutions for this:

1. float the parent div.
2. give the popup a fixed height (for example `height:70%;`)
3. use `display:inline-block;` instead of `floats` to position children

Comment: I would be able to provide a more apropriate answer if I could have an insight of the whole code concerning the popup and it's children(html and css)

Comment: You are right. The second option won't get my desired effect.

Comment: I have uploaded www.allcoles.com/index.php which is a 70% max height, and www.allcoles.com/index2.php which is bottom 15%
I will try making the child an inline-block

Comment: @user3329933 I had a look at you site. Try removing `position:absolute;` on `div#popup_content2` line 112 of your `popups.css`

Comment: That is brilliant - www.allcoles.com/index3.php.  Why would position:absolute be a problem?

Comment: because the `height:auto;` of the parent doesn't count the floated , absolutely or fixed positioned children.

Comment: Now that (position: absolute) in the child div has gone, I have noticed that with the max-height set at 70% which is what I want, I have now lost my overflow-y? When the window is resized, the floating objects float over the parent div.  Is there a way to tackle that bit too...  www.allcoles.com/index.php    - I heavily rely on them floating so cannot change the inside.

Comment: adding `overflow-y: auto;` on `#toPopup1` should get you on the right path.

Comment: Sorry one last question, and I think everything will be good.  My div.close (the x in the top-right corner) which uses a relative position and floats right has gone after adding the overflow, which I guess is because its inside the div and has not gone.  Also the spac_ecs tooltip which I guess has the same problem on hover.  How to I bring them to the front?

Comment: you can us `position:fixed;` and a high z-inex value to position it.